Filtrar dados de um relacionamento N-M Laravel
I need help because I don't know how to do a search and I don't know if there's a way to do it through a query or if the only way is to use a foreach.
I have two tables, a table called 'leads', which is a table of users and a table of plays that I named 'plays'.
The user can have multiple moves and one move belongs to a single user.
In this play table, a column called 'time' is his playing time.
On the website there is a ranking list, which lists the users who played that day and who had the shortest playing time. What I need to do is bring all the players, from the same month and day, ordering from the shortest time to the longest. This is already done, the problem now is. I can't bring the same user twice, I have to filter his best move and show the best move, that is, the move that took the shortest time.
Can anyone help me? Below I currently have the query
Query:
$data = Lead::query();
$data = $data->with('plays', function($query){
        $query->whereMonth('played_at', '=', Carbon::now()->month)->whereDay('played_at', '=', Carbon::now()->day);
});
$data = $data->get();


why not order the plays by their time and get the first one? You question is not clear, do you want both, example: plays of this day AND shortest play in all time?

with() is for eager loading relationships (and adding conditions to eager loaded data).
If you only want to query the leads that have a relationship with that condition, you need to use whereHas
$leads = Lead::query()
    // Get only Leads that have plays where month/day is today's month/day
    ->whereHas('plays', function ($query) {
        $query->whereMonth('played_at', Carbon::now()->month)
            ->whereDay('played_at', '=', Carbon::now()->day);
    })
    // Eager load those Leads's plays relationship
    ->with('plays')
    ->get();

$leads = Lead::query()
    // Get only Leads that have plays where played_at's month/day is today's month/day
    ->whereHas('plays', function ($query) {
        $query->whereMonth('played_at', Carbon::now()->month)
            ->whereDay('played_at', '=', Carbon::now()->day);
    })
    // Eager load those Leads's plays relationship
    ->with(['plays' => function ($query) {
        // only eager load the plays where played_at's month/day is today's month/day
        $query->whereMonth('played_at', Carbon::now()->month)
            ->whereDay('played_at', '=', Carbon::now()->day);
    }])
    ->get();


Eloquent Relationships - Constraining Eager Loads (with)
Eloquent Relationships - Querying Relationship Existence (whereHas)


Man, that wasn't my question, but thanks for the explanation
